Does $y\to x,y’’\to-\frac{y’’}{y’^3}$ always convert a differential equation into that of the inverse function’s?
The inverse substitution  $y\to x$ implies $\frac{dy^{-1}(x)}{dy}=\frac1{y’(x)},\frac{d^2y^{-1}(x)}{dy^2}=-\frac{y’’(x)}{y’^3(x)}$, so $y’\to \frac1{y’}$ and $y’’\to-\frac{y’’}{y’^3}$.
It seems to transform a differential equation into one for the inverse function:
$$2 x(x-1)y’’ +(5x-3) y’+y=0\\\to2(y-1)yy’'-(5y-3) y'^2-x y’^3=0$$
which  inverts $\frac{\tanh^{-1}(\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x}$.
As another example
$$y’’=xy\\\to-\frac{y’’}{y’^3}=xy$$
transforms the Airy differential equation into $-y’’=xyy’^3$ to invert the  Airy functions.
The inverse substitution seems to work because it does so on the above 2 examples. This is part of the answer to if the substitution is the way to convert a differential equation for a function into that of its inverse which is useful. However, it is not clear if this is always true.
Does this substitution always give the differential equation for the inverse of a function?

The answer is yes.
Suppose $y$ has an inverse $I$, so $y(I(t))=t$ for every $t$ in the image of $y$. Starting from a second order differential equation
$$F\left(x,y(x),y'(x),y''(x)\right)=0\tag{1}$$
we can evaluate the left side at $x=I(t)$ to get
$$F\left(I(t),y\left((I(t)\right),y'\left(I(t)\right),y''(I(t))\right)=0$$
$$\implies F\left(I(t),t,y'\left(I(t)\right),y''(I(t))\right)=0\tag{2}$$
Using the relations
$$y'(I(t))=\frac{1}{I'(t)},\text{ }y''(I(t))=-\frac{I''(t)}{(I'(t))^3}$$
then yields a differential equation that we can solve for $I$:
$$F\left(I,t,\frac{1}{I'},-\frac{I''}{(I')^3}\right)=0\tag{3}$$
Notice that $(3)$ is precisely the result of applying your substitutions to $(1)$, so your procedure always yields a differential equation for a (local) inverse of $y$. This generalizes to equations of any order, just compute and use the corresponding formulas for $y^{(3)}(I(t))$, $y^{(4)}(I(t))$, and so on. You'll need some conditions on the derivatives $y^{(n)}$ to ensure the corresponding derivatives $I^{(n)}$ exist; for example, $I'$ exists if $y'$ exists and is never zero.
It is crucial that $y$ have at least a local inverse on some open set. For instance, the initial value problem $y'=0, y(0)=0$ has $y\equiv 0$ as its only solution, which has no inverse. Attempting to apply the substitution $y'\to 1/I'$ transforms the equation to $1/I'=0$, which leads to the contradiction $1=0$.

Thanks for the informative answer. It is also useful to have $Y(x)=\int_0^xy(t)dt,y(0)=0$ in differential equations. It seems one substitutes $Y\to x  y-Y$ from the integral of inverse functions theorem. Is this right or what does one substitute then?

@TymaGaidash sorry for the late reply! Did you mean for $Y$ to be the antiderivative of $y^{-1}$?

Starting with the differential equation for $y$, $Y$ is the primitive for $y$. From there, what would $Y(I(t))$ and substitution be? Thanks

@TymaGaidash You can prove that $Y(I(t)) = tI(t) - \int I(t)dt$ by differentiating, so if you’re solving for $I$, one substitution would be $Y \rightarrow xI \to \hat{I}$, where $\hat I$ is an antiderivative of $I$. Note: you need to make $Y$ appear in the differential equation first, so you need to transform $F(x,y,y’,\dots)$ into something in terms of $Y$.

Maybe you mean $Y\to xI-\hat I$ instead of $Y\to xI\to\hat I$?

@ТymaGaidash  I didn’t even notice that typo. Yes, I meant $Y\rightarrow xI - \hat I$; my mistake.
